# PHP Title change including header

Tags: php, title

I have problem changing every title of page, as in my every page there is index included, my current setup is:

in index.php:

```
<?php

$title = "Your title goes here";

?>
```

in custompage.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

This is what i tried and is working great, but index.php is without title, how can i fix that?

Comment: How do you include custompage.php in your index.php?

Comment: Just include the title tags from your custompage.php into your index, that will echo the title on your index as well

Comment: The problem is that IN index theres included customapege, so if i move <title><?php echo $title; ?></title> under custompage include, it works but index is without title, if i enter <title></title> on top of index it will override all pages with that.